# Navigation Component inside a dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-navigation

I have a dialog that should switch between multiple layouts based on button clicks in a menu. These different layouts each has different logic accompanied to their UI (kind of like switching between multiple forms) so what I tried to do is having a FragmentContainer with its own dedicated NavGraph inside the dialog, hide it until the user chooses from the menu and inflate it to fill the dialog on button click.

**The problem:** The first time everything works as intended - I set the FragmentContainerView to always be visible and I can see the "home" screen, and when I press a button the fragment changes.
When I close and reopen the dialog the FragmentContainer will display nothing (no views are visible despite the fragment onCreateView being called).

Custom dialog XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
        android:id="@+id/motion_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/dialog_scene">

        //... Some views and buttons

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_nav_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/frameLayout"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/frameLayout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/frameLayout"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/dialog_nav_graph" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Nav graph:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/filter_dialog_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/realEstateFilter">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/dialog_home"
        android:name="com.app.Fragments.dialog_home"
        android:label="dialogHome" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_dialogHome_to_otherScreen"
            app:destination="@id/otherScreen" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/otherScreen"
        android:name="com.app.Fragments.other_screen"
        android:label="otherScreen" />
</navigation>
```

Where I handle the navigation inside the dialog:

```
private void initializeViews(View view){
        mNavHost = (NavHostFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.dialog_nav_fragment);
        mNavController = mNavHost.getNavController();
        mNavController.popBackStack(R.id.dialogHome, false); // I want the navigation default destination to be a certain form when the dialog is first opened

        MotionLayout motionLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.motion_layout);
        motionLayout.setTransitionListener(new MotionLayout.TransitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTransitionStarted(MotionLayout motionLayout, int startId, int endId) {
                switch (endId){
                    case R.id.start: {
                        state = UiState.MENU;
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.transition: {
                        state = UiState.FILTER;
                        mNavController.navigate(R.id.action_dialogHome_to_otherScreen;
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.transition2:{
                        state = UiState.FILTER;
                        mNavController.popBackStack(R.id.dialogHome, false);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Any idea on what might be the problem?
In general is this a good approach for switching multiple screens or navigation inside a dialog doesn't work well together? Any general suggestions?

Comment: I faced some issue. Do you find solution for it?